# multi-vender wooCommerce ability to separate products based on zip code

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, location-search

I have a multi-vendor WooCommerce equipment rental website where venders from multiple locations are able to offer their equipment for rent in their area.

Currently I have all the products in the same product categories and subcategories.

Is there a way to make a user choose their location first, and then all the products will be filtered out for them based on their location until they change their location preserving the directory structures?

I know I can use MDTF to filter out products by location but that filter is not permanent. Once the user chooses a different category/subcategory, the filter goes away.

Thanks a lot